# Transparent Desktop Widget in Python

Tags: python

I would like to write a desktop widget that has a transparent window and background, like Rainmeter, using Python. Also I should be able to lock the window in place, and make it so that it can not be above any other windows (ex. It can't be layered over Firefox). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends mostly on your OS and toolkit, and not so much Python.  Any GUI library that supports opacity and has Python bindings, e.g., [GTK+](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-opacity), will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

if you're just looking for a graphic library, you can take a look at wx, that has a vaery powerful tool in make a windows transparent ([this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames) is funny and show you how powerful it is)